# cannot set property of undefined in a loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm doing a loop to generate array of object. I have used faker to generate fake name, but in specified iteration I want to insert my own value, in this case the person's car.
Below code I got cannot set property of car of undefined, what's wrong?

```
const person = []
times(2, index => {
  if (index === 0) {
    person[0].car = 'honda'
  } else if(index ===1) {
    person[1].car = 'ford'
  }

  person.push({
    name: faker.random.name()
  })
}
console.log(person)
```

Comment: you need to create an object before assigning to it: `person[0]={}` and it is likely not a const and is faker.random.name a function that returns an object?

Comment: `if (index === 0) person[0]...`…?! That should simply be `person[index]...`…

Comment: use *const person = Array(2).fill({})*

Comment: you should maybe read this article on [assigning identifiers](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75)

Comment: @mplungjan persons is an array

Comment: @iLuvLogix it's not about const, let or var problem

Comment: @NeiniAmanda It doesn't matter that `person` is an array. If you create an array like this, there will be no elements in it. So if you use `person[0]` it returns `undefined` and `undefined` doesn't have a `car` property. That is why you first need to assign an empty object to it, so that you can add items to it. So before `person[0].car` add `person[0]={}`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from some closing parentheses missing, you try to first access an unexisting object (`person[0].car...`), and create it later (`person.push(...)`).

Reverse the order.

```
let newPerson = { name: faker.random.name(), car: 'dodge' };
person.push(newPerson);
```

Comment: The same. Only you repeat the "newPerson =...; person.push(newPerson);" as many times as you need, can be inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

`person` is an empty array initially, there are no objects in it, so when trying to do `person[0].car` it throws error because `person[0]` is `undefined` and and you cannot set or get any property from `undefined`.

Instead do this

```
person[0] = {}
person.car = 'honda'
```

or

```
person[0] = {'car': 'honda'}
```